# Extra character parsing xml http response

Tags: ruby, soap

I'm running into a bizarre issue.

The following code results in

`response_string` being `"00172C77BC0CDFC4FDB97E5DB0D114B5BE6"`.The web service is actually returning `"0172C77BC0CDFC4FDB97E5DB0D114B5BE6"` (1 less zero in front)

```
response = http.request(request)
n = Nokogiri::XML::parse(response.body)
response_string = n.text        
log "#{response_string}\n"  #==00172C77BC0CDFC4FDB97E5DB0D114B5BE6
```

Here's the response from the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Body>
        <GetNextSUACINtimeRTResponse xmlns="https://<my website>/">
            <GetNextSUACINtimeRTResult>
                <Status>
                    <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
                    <StatusMessage />
            </Status>
            <Response>0172C77BC0CDFC4FDB97E5DB0D114B5BE6</Response>  #<--
        </GetNextSUACINtimeRTResult>
    </GetNextSUACINtimeRTResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

I can figure out how to strip off the first character to workaround the issue but that doesn't seem the best way to solve the issue.

Comment: If you use `text` it gets all the text within the xml you receive, hence the 0 from StatusCode, or not? Maybe you'd just need to access the response attribute? `n.xpath('//Response').text`

Comment: Thank you!  That was it.  I also needed to remove the namespaces:

 n = Nokogiri::XML::parse(response.body)
 n.remove_namespaces!
 response_string = n.xpath('//Response').text 
 log "#{recipe_name}: SUAC: #{response_string}\n"